# Helm string variable - Is it possible to replace a placeholder in a string variable with another helm variable value?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart which has a CRD yaml as follows

```
.......
.......
arguments:
   parameters:
     - name: {{ .Values.workflow_template_command_name }}
       value: "echo '{{ .Values.notebook_details }}'| jq .run_id > /tmp/info.txt"
.......
.......
```

The string variable `notebook_details` in `values.yaml` has a placeholder which I would like to replace with another variable defined in values.yaml.

something like this?

`value: "echo '{{ .Values.notebook_details |replace 'PLACEHOLDER' .Values.text }}'| jq .run_id > /tmp/info.txt"`

Is it possible? if so, whats the right syntax?

Answer (score 8):

The Helm documentation includes a [Template Function List](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/); if you look at the list of string functions, there is a [`replace`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#replace) function.

If you want to take the string from `.Values.notebook_details`, and replace the string literal `PLACEHOLDER` with the value in `.Values.text`, the template syntax is almost exactly what you have, but with double quotes around the string literal (it doesn't matter that it's in a double-quoted YAML string):

```yaml
value: "echo '{{ .Values.notebook_details | replace "PLACEHOLDER" .Values.text }}' | jq ..."
```

Another approach to consider is to allow Helm templating in the value itself.  Documented elsewhere is the [Helm `tpl` template function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) which will evaluate a string as a template

```yaml
value: "echo '{{ tpl .Values.notebook_details . }}' | jq ..."
```

```yaml
# values.yaml
notebook_details: The text is {{ .Values.text }}.
text: replaced by the `tpl` function
```